Why does exit() in a "with open..." block cause 31 to be printed on Terminal?
I'm trying to track down an error about exiting while a file is open.  In doing so, I interactively (not in an IDE, just into Terminal after running Python) entered the following code snippet to Python 3.9:
>>> import csv
>>> with open ("deleteMe", "w", newline="") as f:
...     dmcsv = csv.writer(f)
...     dmcsv.writerow(["this should be a line of text"])
...     exit()
... 
31

As you can see, it printed 31 on the Terminal.  Why? What does that mean?
I'm running on macOS Sonoma (14.6.1)
I was expecting either for Python to silently exit (which is what happens when I just type exit() to the Python interactive prompt), or to give me an error message about trying to write to a closed file (which my original real code yields, and I'm trying to track down).

Anytime you execute an expression in Python's interactive mode that produces a non-None value, it is automatically printed.  The call to .writerow() returned 31 (the number of characters written), so that's what got printed.

(This is pretty confusing and not how people expect things to work, which is why IPython doesn't handle things that way. Usually people only want to auto-print expression values when an expression statement is the entire input, not when an expression statement is part of a block.)

Actually, when you are using Python interactively, this is exactly what you would expect. It is properly call the REPL (Read Evaluate Print Loop). Note the Print part.

@jasonharper Thanks, that's helpful.  It makes a bit more sense.  I had thought it was the value of some error code that was elicited by maybe the exit().  But what about the preceding line: dmcsv = csv.writer(f)?  It returned a non-None value but nothing was printed.  Shouldn't it have printed something like <_csv.writer object at 0xsomeHexHere>?

@AllAboutMike: And yet, the questioner didn't expect it. The whole autoprint-even-in-a-block thing is almost exclusively triggered by accident, and usually just scrolls stuff people were actually interested in off the screen when they accidentally trigger it in a loop.

And it triggers inside a with or a for statement, but not inside a class statement. There's a rule for what expression statements do or don't trigger it, but the rule produces less useful behavior than alternatives do, and doesn't line up with what people would expect before they learn the rule.

@user2357112 I guess I ought to have said people "should" expect output when using the REPL. Type in stuff, it prints the result. The only confusing part might be that the REPL needs to get to the end of the block before it evaluates. Had the write command not been in a block, it would immediately have printed the result.

The other part of the answer to my question (not the main part) is that I should have used sys.exit() rather than exit() in my code.  I was interactively testing this snippet because I was getting errors in my real code along the lines of trying to perform i/o operations on a file that was already closed.  In my real code, when I changed exit() into sys.exit(), those errors went away.  I believe the issue is that exit() is only really for interactive mode, and sys.exit() should be used in code.

The site module (which is imported automatically during startup,
except if the -S command-line option is given) adds several constants
to the built-in namespace (e.g. exit). They are useful for the
interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs.

This was mentioned in Difference between exit() and sys.exit() in Python
